# getting latitude and longitude using geocoder but the longitude and latitude are not accurate

Tags: javascript, html, google-geocoder

I first used Place Autocomplete to get a location name e.g Paris. 
the system then retrieves the geolocation of Paris. But the retrieved geolocation is -77.19452469999999 and 40.337568 which is not the coordinate of Paris.

```
<form>
    <div class=" search-container">
        <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" style="width:50%; margin: 1%;" onchange="GetLatlong();" />
        <input type="submit"  class="btn-info" id="submit" name="submit" style="width:50%; margin: 1%; " />
    </div>
</form>
```

here is the Javascript code

```
function GetLatlong()
  {
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     var address = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          // 

   window.location.href="http://localhost/disert/placesautocomplet/index.php? 
   longitude="+ longitude+"&latitude="+latitude;
        alert(longitude);
        alert(latitude);
      }
   });
 }
```

How can I get the right coordinates instead of the one I am getting.